# Heroku: LoadError: cannot load such file -- mimemagic/overlay

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an error when uploading a release to heroku.

!     LoadError: cannot load such file -- mimemagic/overlay

I successfully ran the 'bundle exec rake -P' command as advised but could not see any mimemagic in the output. I've never had to think about mimemagic before. I think its pulled in by other gems, notably 'carrierwave'. I've found a conversation (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41757) where them gem has been amended in the last few days and wonder whether I've been caught by a breaking update.

Comment: It seems my project has been affected by the mimemagic gem maintaniers removing the 'freedesktop' mime-info database from the gem because the license is GPL and the gem is intended to have an MIT license.

Answer (score 5):

Mimemagic is a dependency of Marcel which is a dependency of a dependency of ... ActiveStorage. The maintainers just changed the license (I think this week), which caused a ruckus.

You want mimemagic at a version between 3.6 and 3.9. You could set it in your Gemfile `gem "mimemagic", "~> 0.3.6"`. Then run `bundle update marcel mimemagic`. If you're on a mac, run `brew install shared-mime-info` first.

Comment: This worked for me. Using any other version of mimemagic other than  `gem 'mimemagic', '~> 0.3.6'` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, just update rails version to

```
gem "rails", "~> 5.2.5"
```

then *bundle update*

Comment: I'd recommend running `bundle update rails` (just update the rails gem) instead of `bundle update` (which will try to update every gem it can and may give you a headache!).

Answer (score 1):

**What worked** was updating rails in my gemfile to `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.5'` and *then* running `bundle update` as @asharijuang mentioned above.

Then I was able to finally push to Heroku after being stuck on this for a few days

A few of the things I tried unsuccessfully:

`gem install mimemagic`

`brew install shared-mime-info` *then* `bundle update marcel mimemagic`

Answer (score 0):

In the end is was quite simple.
Include:-
gem 'mimemagic', '~> 0.3.10'
in the Gemfile. The entry specifically requires a set version, thus avoiding the versions that got pulled. At some point in the future I'll replace 'carrierwave' with the vanilla 'ActionStorage'.